# Why does my Google App Engine preinstall script fail due to Ubuntu (security.ubuntu.com) returning 404?

Tags: google-app-engine, puppeteer, ubuntu-16.04, google-appengine-node

### Goal: I am trying to make puppeteer run on GAE flex instance.

## Intermediate Goal (and source of problem): installing dependencies during a GAE flex instance `gcloud app deploy`

Add. Info:

- I had puppeteer previously running on a standard env, but now I need a flex
  instance bc websockets are not supported in standard.

#### What have I tried

I tried following [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1036) advice. This gentleman apparently made it work:
by adding this in `scripts` in `package.json`:

```
"preinstall": "apt-get update && apt-get -y install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget",
```

Just for fun, I tried apt instead of apt-get. I also tried to pretty crudely copy paste the RUN script instead given [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker) for a different use case:

```
apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

But they all fail on some variation of 404 from security.ubuntu ? They all lead to something like this:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/libpython3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Step #1: 
Step #1: E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/python3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Step #1: 
Step #1: E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/libpython3.5-stdlib_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Step #1: 
Step #1: E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/python3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Step #1: 
Step #1: E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1v5_0.4.11-5ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Step #1: 
Step #1: E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xdg-utils/xdg-utils_1.1.1-1ubuntu1.16.04.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Step #1:
```

I frequently read that puppeteer on flex cannot be done, but I am failing WAY earlier. Does anybody know why my build is not running through? The server does indeed reply 404 for those urls given. What is going on?

Comment: Update: I ended up using the a custom environment and brought my own dockerfile. Would have liked to avoid that since only a few libraries were missing. But it seems there is no workaround otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure what was exactly the reason for it failing initially but switching to custom runtimes and building your own image with required dependencies is usually way to go whenever you feel issue is caused by limitations of base image.

Comment: @SLLegendre Could you please post your solution as an answer and accept it. This will increase the visibility for future users dealing with similar issues. Thanks in advance!